# Put dynamic value into form automatically

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that books a users lesson. I use `lesson.lesson_instrument` and `lesson.lesson_datetime_start` to display the instrument and date of the lesson. I want my form to use the value of `lesson.lesson_instrument`and `lesson.lesson_datetime_start` in `form.booked_instrument` and `form.booked_date`, so that information is saved in a new separate model instance. I was wondering how to get the value from that, into the form text input without typing it.

HTML

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="ins-left">
            <p>{{ lesson.lesson_instrument }} {{ form.booked_instrument }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="date-right">
            <p>{{ lesson.lesson_datetime_start|date}} {{ form.booked_date }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Length</label>
        {{ form.booked_length }}
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Time</label>
        {{ form.booked_time }}
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn blue_button">Book Now</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

forms.py

```
class BookedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    booked_instrument = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    booked_length = forms.ChoiceField(choices=length_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'id' : 'length', 'required' : 'True'}))
    booked_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    booked_time = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'id' : 'time', 'required' : 'True'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Booked
        fields = ('booked_instrument', 'booked_length', 'booked_date', 'booked_time')
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `ModelChoiceField` instead of your current `ChoiceField`.  Like the name suggests the ModelChoiceField ties together a specific model to a ChoiceField giving you exactly what you're looking for.

In essence like Django's docs show:

```
booked_instrument = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Instruments.objects.query(lesson=current_lesson...)
```

where `current_lesson` is the instance of the current lesson being shown or you can filter by other criteria, or just render all instruments that you have on the db.

Take a look at the docs:
[ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

Comment: I don't have an Instrument object, just a Lesson object. So how would I query from that Lesson to get lesson_instrument value as I am new to the ModelChoiceField concept.

Comment: You would need to create a model called Instruments. This will allow you to store things like "guitar" or "cello" and be able to reference to it throughout your application. It should make it easier and more performant if you choose to do that.